# Angular + openLayers. Удаление features при поиске

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, openlayers

У меня есть тестовая карта с двумя слоями vectorLayer и TileLayer и выпадающий список стран для поиска. При выборе нужной страны и нажатии на кнопку найти, нужная страна подствечивается контуром, то есть добавляется доп. слой наложения, то есть таким способом можно выделить все страны. Но мне нужно, чтобы при поиске страны предыдущая удалялась но при вызове метода "removeFeatures" вылетает исключение в коде JS: "Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined". Как это правильно реализовать? Метод для поиска:

```
public searchLocation(event: Event): void {
    this.highlight = this.vector?.getSource().getFeatureById('RUS')!;
    this.featureOverlay = new VectorLayer({
      source: new VectorSource({ useSpatialIndex: false }),
      map: this.map,
      style: (feature) => {
        this.highlightStyle.getText().setText(feature.get('name'));
        return this.highlightStyle;
      },
    });

    var feature = this.vector
      ?.getSource()
      .getFeatureById(this.selectedCountry.id!);

    if (feature !== this.highlight!) {
      if (this.highlight!) {
        this.featureOverlay?.getSource().removeFeature(this.highlight);
      }
      if (feature) {
        this.featureOverlay?.getSource().addFeature(feature);
      }

      this.highlight = feature!;
    }
  }
```

Comment: `Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined` то есть, объект для которого вы вызываете forEach равен `undefined`, то фактически не задан, или не существует. Ищите причину

Comment: Так в том то и дело, что объект this.highlight существует и задаётся я по отладчику смотрел, а коде JS исключение. Может я не правильно задаю?

Comment: @DENIS так если Вы по отладчику смотрели, то почему тогда не зашли в отладчике в функцию removeFeature и не посмотрели что туда приходит? Мало того что он существует он же еще массивом должен быть

Answer (score 0):

this.featureOverlay создавался каждый раз при вызове события и поэтому нужная features при удалении не запоминалась в дереве элементов. И поэтому браузер указывал на forEach.